# Return IP Address as a View Data on ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, model, return, ip, viewdata

I have this Model

```
  public class ArticleVote:BaseEntity
{

    [Display(Name = "UserId")]
    public long? UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserIp { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "ArticleId")]
    public long ArticleId { get; set; }
```

}

and this is my method for get IP Address:

```
     public string GetUserIpAddress()
    {

        string strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
        IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
        IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
        string ip = addr[1].ToString();

        return ip;

    }
```

Now I need IP Address in one of my view page .So I want to use it as a ViewData
How can I use it on my Controller?
I have several method and its view has another View Model. I want to use just this GetUserIpAddress  Method inside one of my method.so I have to use from View Data. I know I had to write:

```
 var userIp = ???.GetUserIpAddress();

        ViewData["userIp"] = userIp;
```

How can I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Find My Mistake.
I have to write :

```
 var userIp = _articleService.GetUserIpAddress();

        ViewData["UserIp"] = userIp;
```

Because I have to call in from service

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ViewBag` or `ViewData` to pass values from a controller to a view if you don't want to or can't use a view model. Here is an example of both:

```
public IActionResult YourAction()
{
    // With a ViewBag
    ViewBag.UserIp = "178.94.293.29";

    // With a ViewData
    ViewData["UserIp"] = "178.94.293.29";

    return View();
}
```

Then in your view, you can access the data like this:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<span>Get ViewBag value: @ViewBag.UserIp</span>
<span>Get ViewData value: @ViewData["UserIp"]</span>
```

Comment: @hasti.au, Are you trying to pass the IP address to a view?

Comment: yes. but as I said my view has another view model.so I want to use View Data. @Gabe

Comment: @hasti.au, Oh; I think I understand your question now. I'm going to update my answer to address your issue.

Comment: I use this method on my repository ,now in controller I want get the IP that have received from method on repository. so in controller I had to write :
 var userIp = ????.GetUserIpAddress();
   
            ViewData["userIp"] = userIp;
Then on view I can use it. But I don't know how to Extract it from method in repository. @gabe

Comment: @hasti.au, Are you calling the repository method from your controller?

Comment: Sorry. it is in Service layer. and I inject my service in controller too.

Comment: I Find my mistake , and update my answer. but now I don't know how to use on view . It s for like. I want to show . if click on SVG : get another class that became red.
     <button type="submit">
                                                <svg id="comment-heart" @(_articleService.IsArticleLikedByUser(((userIp.UserIp)).Result)?"Zhaskhgusdhasdhfadshfasdhf":""))...>

Comment: @hasti.au Try using a ViewBag like shown in my example instead of a ViewData